# IBM IMM2 JNLP WEB CONSOLE 405 ERROR

Tags: ibm, imm2

I'm going to use the IBM X3550 M4 to access the remote console.

But there's a problem.

Application Error: Unable to start the application.

NAME : Virtual KVM Client
publisher : IBM
position : https://200.168.10.254 : 443

ERROR : Server returned HTTP response code : 405 for URL:

https://200.168.10.254:443/designs/imm/aessrp/avctIBMViewer__V092815.jar

I want to use the IMM2 Web console.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem.
Solved by cleaning Java Temporary Internet Files.

Comment: Bloody hell this worked.

Comment: Can confirm, works!